# Filter a dataframe based on a condition of another column

Tags: r

I am trying to filter my dataframe. Basically my data looks like this:

```
year   value
2010    '-'
2010   '$64'
2011    '-'
2011   '$50'
2012    '-'
2013    '-'
2013   '$87'
```

And I want to get rid of the '-' values unless it is the only value for one year. So the output would look something like this:

```
year    value
2010    '$64'
2011    '$50'
2012     '-'
2013    '$87'
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! I'm sure this is a simple solution, but I'm having trouble figuring it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option with `filter` after grouping by 'year'.  We would check whether the value is not equal to `-` and the number of distinct elements are greater than 1 or (`|`) if there is a single element (`n() == 1`) and that value is '-'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(year) %>%
   filter( value != '-' & n_distinct(value) > 1| (value == '-') & n() == 1)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   year [4]
#   year value
#  <int> <chr>
#1  2010 $64  
#2  2011 $50  
#3  2012 -    
#4  2013 $87
```

---

Or a slightly more compact option is to get the rows where 'value' is not equal to '-' or (`|`) where the number of elements that are `-` in 'value' is equal to the number of rows

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(year) %>%
  filter( sum(value == '-') == n()| value != '-')
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(year = c(2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 
2013L), value = c("-", "$64", "-", "$50", "-", "-", "$87")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option with `subset` + `ave`

```
subset(
  df,
  as.logical(
    ave(value,
      year,
      FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)) > 1 & x != "-" | length(unique(x)) == 1
    )
  )
)
```

which gives

```
  year value
2 2010   $64
4 2011   $50
5 2012     -
7 2013   $87
```

Answer (score 1):

A step by step solution with `base R`would be:

```
#Create unique values
dfun <- aggregate(value~year,df,function(x) length(unique(x)))
#Add to original dataframe
df$Var <- dfun[match(df$year,dfun$year),"value"]
#Create a flag
df$Flag=ifelse(df$value=="'-'" & df$Var>1,1,0)
#Filter
df2 <- subset(df,Flag==0)
df2$Var <- NULL
df2$Flag <- NULL
```

Output:

```
  year value
2 2010 '$64'
4 2011 '$50'
5 2012   '-'
7 2013 '$87'
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(year = c(2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 
2013L), value = c("'-'", "'$64'", "'-'", "'$50'", "'-'", "'-'", 
"'$87'"), Var = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Flag = c(1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```